# Emails are automatically marked as read after a few seconds

Tags: mail.app, email, imap

I have a problem that potentially causes me to miss important email: An incoming message is automatically marked as read after a few seconds. One can watch how a new email is at first unread in the inbox and then turns to read.
This problem seems to occur only for one of several IMAP accounts.

My settings are: In the viewing tab a selection "Mark all messages as read when opening a conversation" check box is unset.

What could cause this?
How can I diagnose if the problem is on the server side or if Mail.app is malfunctioning?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this issue? I'm facing the exact same problem

Comment: @scanales Yes, see my answer below. Really annoying problem.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I am having the same problem on my iPhone. only with one IMAP account. I also have already unselected the box next to "mark all messages as read when opening a conversation" and can't find any other settings anywhere that seem to impact this. It is not my mail server as the account is working fine on my Laptop. I deleted the account and recreated it several times hoping it would resolve itself, but no luck. That was when I sent myself a test and realized that the Laptop was functioning correctly when the account did not exist on my iPhone so I am quite confiden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to fix the issue: In fact, it was the fault of OS X Server.

[image]

In the server app, under the calendar tab, there is a checkbox "activate invitations via e-mail". The problem disappeared when I unchecked it!

Comment: Oh, ok, I'm not running an OS X Server. I'll keep digging. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Uncheck (Mail->Preferences->Viewing) 'Use classic layout'.

Answer (score -2):

When setting up your email account, make sure to choose POP3 instead of IMAP. It worked for me, and I had the exact same issue.

Comment: This is a _very_ bad idea of you want to access your mail from multiple devices, as they're not synchronized _with_ the server any more, but fetched _from_ (and usually deleted afterwards).

Comment: You can't actually *do* that unless your mail server supports both methods.